# Записать файл с цифрами 0, 1 в массив 2х8

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, помогите записать с помощью потоков файл в массив...
Что-то у меня не получается...
Вот примерный код:

```
ifstream stream;
stream.open("67.txt",ios::in);

int s=0;
    stream >> f[i][j];

    for(i=0; i<2;i++)
        for(j=0; j<8;j++)
        {
            if(t[i][j]==1)
                 s=1;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так (если нули и единицы разделены пробелами; если нет, скажите, напишу)

```
ifstream fs ("file");
    if (! fs.is_open()) return 1;
int aa [2][8], n = 0;
while (n < 2*8 && fs >> *((int*) aa + n++));
```

**P.S.** В связи с уточнением условий, предлагаю такой код

```
ifstream fs ("file");
if (! fs.is_open()) {cerr << "Bad file\n"; return 1;}
int a[2][8];
size_t n = 0;
char c;
while (n < 2*8 && fs.read (&c, 1) ) {
    if (c == '0') ((int*) a)[n++] = 0;
    else if ( c == '1') ((int*) a)[n++] = 1;    
}
```

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста строчки:
int aa [2][8], n = 0;
while (n < 2*8 && fs >> *((int*) aa + n++));

Comment: Что-то не заполняется массив, а элемент [2][8] инициализируется нулем..

Comment: покажите, что за файл у вас

Comment: у меня там 101010101111100010101010101.... примерно такое содержание

Comment: т.е. только нули и единицы в одну строчку?

Comment: Да, нули и единицы, но идут вообщем-то не встрочку а так:
101010010101
100101010100
100101011111
000110110101

Answer (score 2):

Вот реализация, правда она считывает файл в одномерный массив, но преобразовать его в двумерный не составит особого труда =)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int n = 80;

int main()
{
    ifstream f("halo.txt");
    int mass[16];
    int c = 0;
    while (!f.eof()) {
        char s[80];
        f.getline(s, n);
        char *tok = strtok(s, " n");
        while (tok) {
            c++;
            mass[c] = atoi(tok);
            tok = strtok(NULL, " n");
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
        cout << mass[i] << endl;
    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: Почему-то Ваша программа зацикливается..